# Uploading media from Image field is uploading as versioned

Tags: media-library

In sitecore 8.2 update 4, when we are uploading image from image field on item, media template is versioned type but when we are directly uploading image in media library then media template is unversioned type
by default

`<setting name="Media.UploadAsVersionableByDefault" value="false"/>`

it is set to false.
Any idea?
And this is happening OOTB for current 8.2 update 4 version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems bug in 8.2 update 4 which is fixed in update 5. Please see this KB article - https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/959696

Please try to apply this solution.

Thanks
Mahendra